# Como adicionar linhas (label) automaticamente em um UICollection em Swift?

Tags: swift, table, collection, label

Na minha aplicação consegui usar o UICollection para mostrar uma "tabela" com rolagem horizontal contendo as informações da compra do cliente com cabeçalho, mas agora tenho outra dúvida, preciso que essa tabela seja alimentada a cada nova senha adicionada. Com o UICollection, eu adicionei 2 label, um com o cabeçalho (CPF, NOME, etc), outro com as informações da chamada no servidor para cada senha escolhida, ou seja, se o usuário comprar uma senha e antes de fechar o pedido escolher mais uma senha, a tabela deve conter o cabeçalho e mais duas linhas com as informações das senhas (mais um label), como adiciono linhas (label) automaticamente no UICollection como numa tableView, há medida que o array de informações (quantidade de senhas) cresce? Segue abaixo imagem da tabela que está funcionando, mas que precisa ser alimentada:

[image: Tabela de senhas]

Comment: Realmente ficou confuso de entender bem oq vc quer, fez e pretende fazer...
Porém ainda creio que para oq vc quer fazer a tableview ainda é mais fácil de utilizar, mas caso queira insistir na UiCollectionView, crie apenas uma cell (item) customizada e crie uma classe UICollectionViewCell para cuidar dela, retornando para cada label os resultados do array.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas da para colocar uma UITableView dentro de uma UICollectionView. A navegação lateral fica por conta da CollectionView e dentro de cada aba você coloca a TableView com UMA seção e  N linhas, adicionadas dinamicamente de acordo com a necessidade.

Aqui existe um sample code em Objective C para o que comentei, só adiciona a seção como grouped para funcionar como header.
https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/TableViewInCollection.zip